# How to correctly set this local-key?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I wrote this code to bind both `Alt+c` and `F5` to `compile`

```
(defun dg/cedet-hook()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-c") 'compile)
  (local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'compile)
  (yas-global-mode 1)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'dg/cedet-hook)
```

But, when I open a .cpp file Emacs returns the following error:

`File mode specification error: (invalid-function (local-set-key (kbd <f5>) (quote compile)))`

I don't understand what's wrong in the syntax above, and why the error triggers in only the statement which uses `F5`. Please note that my configuration doesn't contain any other key binding related to F5.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the code in the question is the same as the code you're executing?  Adding double parens reproduces the error message: `((local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'compile))`.

Comment: Is `local-set-key` defined in your version of Emacs? What does `C-h f local-set-key` tell you?

Comment: NEWS.1-17: "Changes in Emacs 1.3: local-install-command has been renamed to local-set-key." :) Besides, it's not complaining that `local-set-key` is an invalid function. It's complaining that `(local-set-key (kbd <f5>) (quote compile))` is an invalid function. I suspect there is relevant code that has not been included in the question.

Comment: @Drew: The other statements work, so `local-set-key` is surely defined.
Anyway, I tryed `(local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'compile)` and `(local-set-key (kbd <f5>) 'compile)`, always the same error. `(local-set-key [f5] 'compile)` worked, instead.

Comment: What does `M-: (kbd "<f5>") RET` return? For me it returns `[f5]`, which is the same as what you say works.

Comment: It returns `[f5]` too. Is there any way to set a keybinding interactively? Maybe it would help me in debugging this.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`

Comment: `local-set-key` is a command, so you can interactively use `M-x local-set-key`